# Counting Nodes in Circular Linked List with One Parameter?

Tags: c++, circular-list

So I have to count the nodes in a Circular Linked List recursively. I have a header that I am required to use:

```
int Recursive(node *head);
```

Is it possible to count the nodes in this list with only one pointer? What would the algorithm be for that?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? And what specifically about this do you need help with?

Comment: I don't know an algorithm to make this work. If it's circular, and it's recursive, and I can only pass the pointer of the current or next node, how do I make a base case so I can compare it to the head? I have no way to compare the pointer of my current node to the head pointer.

Comment: In theory, you could have a second helper function that takes two parameters: the head and the current node, and have it do the recursive search. Then call it from inside of `Recursive` as `helper(head, head)`. Unless you aren't allowed to use an auxiliary helper function. In C++, you could also just use a recursive inner function, but that won't work in C. Please specify what language you're using, as C and C++ are not the same language, and the answer may vary depending.

Comment: I don't think I am, but I will if I have to. I just didn't know if this was even possible or not.

Comment: Very little isn't possible in programming. It's usually just a question of how clever you need to be.

Comment: Choose: C or C++?

Comment: I shouldn't matter, because I only want to have this one function. Overloading the function or adding a second function is not what I'm trying to do. But I happen to be using C++

Comment: Free clue: it's trivial to 1) check if the list is NULL or has one element, and if so the size of the list is known, otherwise 2) remove the next element from the list, recursively count size of the remaining list, add 1, and then put the next element back where it came from. Problem solved. Maybe about 6-7 lines of code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That sounds like more of an answer than a clue.

Comment: @0x499602D2 - I'm sure it's not. Despite the phrasing in the question, the obvious requested answer here is to actually write the code, and what I wrote is nowhere close to that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't see how that's obvious given the phrasing. The question is asking for the algorithm so giving the algorithm would be the answer to the question.

Comment: No, I just wanted to know if it was possible, I did not need anybody to write code for me. Sam's answer was pretty much what I was asking for.

Comment: Why do you need to make this recursive? A simple iterative loop would work just as well, and avoid the overhead of using, and the risk of overflowing, the call stack for a large list

Comment: It's an assignment I have. I was actually just able to make it work doing something similar to what Sam suggested. I just saved the values in a temp variable, set the real variable to NULL, and used recursion until I bumped into a variable that was NULL, and then re-set the original variables into the proper spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       int count(node* head)
       {
          if(head == nullptr)
            return 0;
         return countRecursive(head, head->next);
       }

       int countRecursive(node* head, node* current)
       {
          if(current == head) // our end condition!
             return 1;
         return 1 + countRecursive(head, current->next);
       }

       Basically we go in a circle and stop when we return to the head, adding 1 while 
       we go.
```

Comment: You have two functions with the same name.  Considering it is asking for C/C++ you should say that your function only works in C++, or rename one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can detach a node to make it into a smaller list, recursively count the nodes in that list and then reattach the additional node. Here you go:

```c++
int count(Node* head) {
  // Base cases: (empty list and 1 node)
  if (!head) return 0;
  if (head->next == head) return 1;
  // Keep a pointer to the node to be removed
  Node* temp = head->next;
  // Remove the node
  head->next = temp->next;
  // Get the length of the new list
  int result = 1 + count(head);
  // Reconnect the node
  head->next = temp;
  return result;
}
```